# Docker compose error services.worker.init must be a boolean

Tags: docker, shopware6

I followed the Shopware production docker image readme here:

https://github.com/shopware/docker

So my docker compose file is copied from the readme:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'shopware'
            MYSQL_USER: shopware
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: shopware
            MYSQL_DATABASE: shopware
        volumes:
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

    init-perm:
        image: alpine
        volumes:
            - files:/var/www/html/files
            - theme:/var/www/html/public/theme
            - media:/var/www/html/public/media
            - thumbnail:/var/www/html/public/thumbnail
            - sitemap:/var/www/html/public/sitemap
        command: chown 82:82 /var/www/html/files /var/www/html/public/theme /var/www/html/public/media /var/www/html/public/thumbnail /var/www/html/public/sitemap

    init:
        image: local
        build:
            context: .
        env_file: .app.env
        entrypoint: /setup
        volumes:
            - files:/var/www/html/files
            - theme:/var/www/html/public/theme
            - media:/var/www/html/public/media
            - thumbnail:/var/www/html/public/thumbnail
            - sitemap:/var/www/html/public/sitemap
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_started
            init-perm:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
    web:
        image: local
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - files:/var/www/html/files
            - theme:/var/www/html/public/theme
            - media:/var/www/html/public/media
            - thumbnail:/var/www/html/public/thumbnail
            - sitemap:/var/www/html/public/sitemap
        depends_on:
            init:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
        env_file: .app.env
        ports:
            - 8000:8000

    worker:
        image: local
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - files:/var/www/html/files
            - theme:/var/www/html/public/theme
            - media:/var/www/html/public/media
            - thumbnail:/var/www/html/public/thumbnail
            - sitemap:/var/www/html/public/sitemap
        depends_on:
        init:
            condition: service_completed_successfully
        env_file: .app.env
        entrypoint: [ "php", "bin/console", "messenger:consume", "async", "--time-limit=300", "--memory-limit=512M" ]
        deploy:
            replicas: 3

volumes:
    mysql-data:
    files:
    theme:
    media:
    thumbnail:
    sitemap:
```

I am running docker 24.0.7 on Ubuntu 22.04, but I am getting:

```
$ docker compose up
validating /xxxxxxxx/docker-compose.yml: services.worker.init must be a boolean
```

sometimes also:

```
docker-compose.yml: services.worker.depends_on must be a list
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to remove the version tag in the docker-compose file and changing it to 3.9 - did not help.

As per https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#init I am not sure, if such a `condition` should be supported.

Comment: Under `worker:`, `init:` needs to be indented two more spaces, so it's a service name under `depends_on:` and doesn't look like a per-service Compose setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the comments - this is what was meant (under worker)

```
        depends_on:
            init:
                condition: service_completed_successfully
```

There is indeed init option existing but in this case it should belong to the `depends_on` clause and refer the service with the name `init`.